# Adding analytics for specific fields in API Connect

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I am currently facing an issue while logging specific field in API Connect analytics for SOAP Services.

There is a section in API Designer Analytics where you can define and specify existing Parameters for your API that can be used to gather analytics data about the API. For REST I have tried and I am getting specified fields in Analytics but for SOAP I am not getting.

I am using version 5.0.8.5

Comment: Please include [a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NinoFiliu the source code generated in API Connect is Swagger Document. So for my question I only need steps that how can I log specific fields in IBM API Connect for XML or SOAP services.